# Reprojecting lat/long onto map after zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map of the United States rendered in D3 similar to here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590

I have circles projected via albersUSA onto the map like so:

```
var site = map.append("circle").attr("r",5).attr("transform", function() {
    return "translate(" + projection([value.longitude,value.latitude]) + ")";
});
```

When the map is clicked, the states and counties are translated and scaled.

However, the latitude/longitude projection is way off and does not move accordingly. I have tried:

```
site.transition()
   .duration(1000)
   .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" +    projection(-x + "," + -y) + ")"
   )
```

However, this does not project to the correct position.

Here is the click function:

```
function clicked(d) {
    console.log("click");
    var x, y, k;

    if (d && centered !== d) {
        var centroid = path.centroid(d);
        x = centroid[0];
        y = centroid[1];
        k = 4;
        centered = d;
    } else {
        x = width / 2;
        y = height / 2;
        k = 1;
        centered = null;
    }

    counties.selectAll("path")
        .classed("active", centered && function (d) {
            return d === centered;
        });

    counties.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
        .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");

    states.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
        .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");

    for (var i = 0; i < sys_list.length; i++) {
        console.log(sys_list[i]);

        sys_list[i].transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + projection(-x + "," + -y) + ")")
    }
}
```

Thanks and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: what are x, y, and k set to?

Comment: Posted the code. Basic click function, set to the centroid of the click.

Comment: What's the difference between the example and what you're trying to do? In particular, which bits did you modify.

Comment: In particular, I have a point that is projected onto the map which doesn't match the correct lat/long when I zoom in